# Custom map data providers in Google Maps for AS3

Tags: flash, google-maps, bing-maps, openstreetmap, yahoo-maps

I'm using Google Map component for AS3 and I want to display map data, provided by OpenStreetMap, Bing Maps, and Yahoo Maps. Is this permitted by Google and these map data providers?
I have created custom map types for these map data providers and properly set the copyrights for all custom map types. The only question is the policy of component and map data usage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there are many Websites that use the GoogleMaps-Api for displaying OSM eg. [Query-to-map](http://toolserver.org/~kolossos/osm/osm-paths-gm.php?kml=http://tools.wikimedia.de/~kolossos/osm/cache/bm9kZVtoaWdod2F5PWVsZXZhdG9yXQ==.kmz).

so i wouldn't dare so much...

but i am not a lawyer.